# Multiple Solana private keys, how do I check each one for a balance?

Tags: cli, balance

I have 100s of solana private keys for a service I'm building. How do I check each one for a balance without having to import them to the solana-cli each time? Is there a simple command to check a private key's balance?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read them into your CLI somehow.  If they're stored in files, you can use `solana_sdk::signer::keypair::read_keypair_file`, get the pubkey, and then get that balance, so some pseudo-code could be:

```
let keypair_path = Path::new("./path/to/keypair.json");
let rpc_client = RpcClient::new("http://localhost:8899");
let kp = read_keypair_file(&keypair_path);
let balance = rpc_client.get_balance(&kp.pubkey());
```

More information at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/1db7da5c32231b2ae72be29173c9ded986544f62/sdk/src/signer/keypair.rs#L124

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you could do a shell script like this to iterate over different wallets in a file, `list.txt`:

list.txt:

```
WALLET_ID_1
WALLET_ID_2
WALLET_ID_3
```

balances.sh:

```
output_file="balances.txt"

while read line; do
    balance=$(solana balance "$line")
    echo "$line: $balance" >> "$output_file"
done < list.txt
```

This should output a file, `balances.txt` that looks something like this:

```
WALLET_ID_1: 1.181062312 SOL
WALLET_ID_2: 2.046516532 SOL
WALLET_ID_3: 3.84642558 SOL
```

if you wanted to do this from private keys saved on your machine (as opposed to public keys, you'd modify your `list` to include file paths to each private key (or have your shell script loop through files in a folder). and add `-k` to your `solana balance` query, eg:

`balance=$(solana balance -k "$path")`

something like:

```
output_file="balances.txt"
directory="/keys/"

for file in in "$directory"/*.json; do
    # Extract public key from private key
    key=$(solana address -k "$file")

    # Get balance from private key
    balance=$(solana balance -k "$file")
    echo "$key: $balance" >> "$output_file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use anchor_lang::{
    prelude::*,
    solana_program::account_info::AccountInfo,


let balance = AccountInfo::lamports(&account.to_account_info())
```

Remember to pass the account as account info

Comment: This solution only works on-chain, and the question is about CLI usage